# Why do I have to turn my cruise control on before I use it?

Tags: cruise-control

I don't have to turn my blinkers or windshield wipers on before I use them but in every car I've ever been in with cruise control, you have to turn it on before you set the cruising speed.

Why should I ever turn cruise control off? Is there a problem with leaving it on all the time and just setting my cruising speed at any time without first having to turn it on?

If there is a technical problem caused by leaving cruise control on, why haven't we solved it? I can tweet from a refrigerator but it seems we just haven't wanted to solve this problem for some reason.

Comment: @NuclearWang You're right. Despite the question sounding like ways to turn off cruise control, it does seem to be entirely about why the system is the way it is.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had a car with a physical switch for cruise control, so mine was always on.  I never bothered to turn it off - I just didn't set a speed.

Answer (score 0):

Safety - so you can only engage it deliberately : otherwise some monkey would not understand why they could not stop...

Comment: hmmm.. I think the reason is that you can shut it off when necessary, no matter what. Having a separate control would give you an independent shut off in the rare instance where the brake interlock to cruise control failed. Agree with the Safety aspect of this answer, but I think its for failsafe duplicity of function.

Comment: @zipzit as some systems have several methods of cancelling cruise (brake operation, clutch operation (on a manual) and even issues with brake llights or ecu signals), on my car it becomes available when relevant ie over a certain speed & in gear but it does not have an "on" switch - it is engaged by the the set rotating type switch... The are only three driver operated controls "cancel" & "resume" and "set"... Absolutely no "on / off"